# Can't catch exceptions from async/await?

Tags: exception, flutter, dart, try-catch

I'm trying to catch a `PlatformException` raised by `FlutterBlue.instance`. I've put a try except block around this await, but the exception still gets raised in my debugger.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';

...

Stream<BluetoothState> _getBluetoothState() async* {
  bool isAvailable = false;
  try {
    // This always raises a PlatformException
    // in the vscode debugger
    isAvailable = await FlutterBlue.instance.isAvailable;
  } on PlatformException catch(e) {
    // This doesn't seem to ever catch anything
    debugPrint('$e');
  } catch(e) {
    // Doesn't catch my exception either.
    debugPrint('$e');
  }

  // Wrap the original stream that fails to handle this exception..
  if (isAvailable) {
    await for (BluetoothState state in FlutterBlue.instance.state) {
      yield state;
    }
  } else {
    yield BluetoothState.unavailable;
  }
}
```

UPDATE: Actually, I'm not even sure this relates to async/wait, I believe `FlutterBlue.instance` is raising the error and that isn't async. It's just a getter.  I'm a dart newbie, and this has me pretty lost.

Comment: what does the stacktrace look like?

Comment: async/await does let you catch exceptions, you should definitely look elsewhere, FWIW.